# Dereferencing interface for basic types

Tags: go, interface

This is a silly example I was playing with to explore interfaces.  I wrapped an interface around an int so that it could speak its value:

```
package intspeaker

import (
        "fmt"
)

type IntSpeaker interface {
        Speak()
}

type SpeakNumber int

func (ic SpeakNumber) Speak()  {
        fmt.Println("My value is ", ic)
}
```

Then I instantiate the interface, initialize the value, and tell it to speak its value:

```
package main
import "./intspeaker"
import "fmt"

func main() {
        var speaker intspeaker.IntSpeaker = intspeaker.SpeakNumber(5)
        speaker.Speak()
        fmt.Println(speaker) // output = 5
        var getIt int = speaker // compile error: cannot use speaker 
                                // (type intspeaker.IntSpeaker) as type int
}
```

Is there any way to dereference the int value from the interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`speaker` contains a concrete value of type `intspeaker.IntSpeaker`. Use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to get that value out of it:

```
var getIt intspeaker.SpeakNumber = speaker.(intspeaker.SpeakNumber)
```

If you need it as an `int`, you may use a further type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to get it as an `int`:

```
var it int = int(getIt)
```

You may leave out the types from the variable declarations (it will be inferred from the right-hand side expressions):

```
var getIt = speaker.(intspeaker.SpeakNumber)
var it = int(getIt)
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/M_xpu1JQEin).

Comment: Yep.   I tried that but had the incorrect syntax.  That's a bit wonky looking to me, coming from the Java world.

Comment: @ArloGuthrie I posted a link to the Go Playground where it works. If it doesn't work for you, you must post the exact code you've tried.

Comment: No, it works.  I was saying I tried doing that but had the wrong syntax.  For some reason there's a timer on marking something as answered. <headscratch/>